# How to filter data in NSMutableArray that contains NSArray as an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to filter data from `NSMutableArray` that contains `NSArray` as an object. Below is code that I have used for set object-

```
[self setFieldType];
NSMutableArray *kirtanList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Id,%@ FROM Kirtan_list  where Title_Eng like '%@%%' or Title_Eng like '%%%@%%' order by Title_Eng", titleField, text,text];
sqlite3_stmt * statement;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        char *field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        NSString *field1Str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field1];
        char *field2 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        NSString *field2Str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field2];
        NSArray *data=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field1Str],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field2Str],nil ];
        [kirtanList addObject:data];
    }
}else{
    NSLog(@"Filtered row error ");
}
```

help me for filter data.

Comment: detect type of class by using [object1 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]

Comment: On what condition do you want to filter the data ?

Comment: using NSPredicate with formate like  NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"AnyName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@",_textField.text];

Comment: Refer this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Comment: not useful above link

Comment: Try this for once.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38007095/3908884

Answer (score 0):

Solve this by this code

```
 NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@",_textField.text];
```

Answer (score -2):

```
NSMutableArray *marrObject=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Declare Array Object

//Loop for find array objects
for (id arrObject in marrObject) {

    if ([arrObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

        NSLog(@"It's Array Object");
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is about to filter NSArray object and i do that.And it's not posssible that i write whole code which is describe in question regarding sqlite.And after finding NSArray object he can do further process.